# css SYNTAX is not displaying list

Tags: html, css

My list is not being displayed

```css
    .thirdrow ul {
                list-style-position: inside;
                font-size: 120%;
                bottom: 0;
                right: 0;
                margin-top: 0.3cm;
                padding-top: 0.6cm;
               }
```

```html
                <div id="thirdrow">
                        <ul>       
                            <li>...</li>
                            <li>...</li>
                        </ul>
                </div>
```

Is my syntax '`.thirdrow ul`' correct in the CSS file?
if not, what's the right one?

Comment: Your list is being displayed. I see no problem. Maybe you have other css in your code that hides it?

Comment: you are using a class selector when you should be using an ID selector `. vs. #` in your css

Comment: chovy ..pls elaborate as I am new

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the selector to - **#thirdrow ul** and that should work.